# Blazor Text Interpolation using lambda

Tags: blazor

I have this in the code behind:

```
protected double GetRate(double manual) => 100 - manual;
```

In my HTML I have this:

```
<MudTd DataLabel="Rate">"@(() => GetRate(context.ManualRate))"  %</MudTd>
```

but this html part is giving me an error of

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

How can I make this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to display the conversion, you don't need a lambda but just a method call:

```
Not: <MudTd DataLabel="Rate">"@(() => GetRate(context.ManualRate))" %</MudTd> 

But: <MudTd DataLabel="Rate">@GetRate(context.ManualRate) %</MudTd>
```

Comment: Yep. I already got this. Thank you for the answer though.